# How to exit test with failer even if there is catch around it?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

Problem is: I need to exit test with fail message. using `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` `Assert.Fail("message");` gets caught via try catch. What can be done to exit test with failer that would not be catchable?

Say my test has something like this inside: `...remoteServerEventHandler(e => /*some logic */ Assert.Fail("message"))` yet it gets handeled via serverEventHandler while I just want to exit with failure in my test.

Comment: Why do you want to catch an exception in a unit test? Just let the exception bubble up, it will indicate a failure.

Answer (score 1):

In catch block, at the end you should write `throw`, which will re-throw the same exception in calling function or to the next block executing.

Answer (score 1):

Check the type of exception and rethrow it if it is an assertion exception.

```
try
{
    // ...
    Assert.Fail("message");
    // ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is AssertFailedException)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

The code assumes you are using MSTest. Change `AssertFailedException` to `AssertionException` if you are using NUnit.

Comment: Not the easiest way if exception handler is not inside testing code - say my test has something like this inside: `...remoteServerEventHandler(e => /*some logic */ Assert.Fail("message"))` yet it gets handeled via serverEventHAndler. while I just want to exit with failure in my test

Comment: Then I think the easiest solution is not to catch `Exception` but to catch something a bit more specific. Typically you don't want to catch `Exception` since that hides programming errors (e.g. `NullReferenceException`) among things.